# WinInet C++ ftp template?

Tags: windows, winapi, ftp, client, wininet

Starting from scratch, would like to create an ftp application using WinInet.
Looking for a real basic example in C++ that will compile and get me started.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of partial samples on [DotNetHeaven](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/CommonHTTPandFTP05242005075834AM/CommonHTTPandFTP.aspx) that could be glued to together without much work.

You could potentially use the MFC [CFTPConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kywsafk(VS.80).aspx) (Which wrap the wininet api) as well, samples here on [DotNetHeaven](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wininetmfcclasses05242005085341am/wininetmfcclasses.aspx) as well.